# Open specific view on receiving Push Notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification, navigationcontroller

I have `UITableView` as my `rootViewController` and I populate that table with parsed RSS (there's a `Parser` class where my `rootViewController` is its delegate). In the `rootViewController` I have methods for refreshing RSS `refreshData` and I keep my retreived data in a static `MutableArray` staticItems:

On clicking a cell in `tableView` cell the `detailView` gets pushed on the  `navigationController` while at the same time (on selecting the cell (row)) I create and pass a dictionary `theItem` to the `detailView`. In that dictionary I pass the values from `staticItems` and the `positionInArray` (index of selected cell). This way I can show the text of the news and keep track about the position of the news in the array of news to implement slide prev/next.

Now, I enabled push notifications and on receiving one my app is back to foreground but with the view that was opened last time when app was closed.

I would like to present the last news in *detailView* by re-parsing (refreshing) the RSS and presenting the last news (theItem[0]).

So, I would like to have the result of the following: calling the `[rootController refreshData]` and then selecting the first item in the cell and opening it in `detailView`

I've been playing with the delegate method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, but I can't find the way of making it work. I tried creating new `rootController`, but then I stack it over existing one :(.

Please share your thoughts with me :)

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan: My question was edited (removed Hi, and thanks at the end) and now my italics are not italics any more. Was I formatting it wrong? thnx

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this question is not really related to push notifications at all. It's more a question of how to access your view controllers from an arbitrary place in your application delegate.

Your best (and possibly only) bet is to manually keep references to the relevant view controller instances.

I'm assuming you use a `UINavigationController` where the root is your list, and then you push a detail view controller onto it. Keep a reference to this navigation controller in your app delegate. Add a `@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *mainNavController;` to your application delegate. When you create the navigation controller, assign it so the app delegate has a reference.

```
MyAppDelegate *ad = ((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);
ad.mainNavController = theNavController;
```

If you create the navigation controller in the app delegate itself, you obviously only need to do this:

```
self.mainNavController = theNavController;
```

Then when you receive a push notification, simply act on the navigation controller directly.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    // Do whatever you need to do in order to create an instance of your
    // detail view controller
    MyDetailViewController *vc = [MyDetailViewController magicalStuff:userInfo];

    // Add the detail view controller to the stack, but keep the root view
    // controller.
    UIViewController *root = self.mainNavController.topViewController;
    NSArray *vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:root, vc, nil];
    [self.mainNavController setViewControllers:vcs animated:YES];
}
```

Then the navigation controller will animate to `MyDetailViewController` with a swipe and the back button will take you to the list.